# Implementation of REINFORCE for continuous action space (humanoid-v2)?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I've seen multiple implementation of the REINFORCE aka Vanilla Policy Algorithm being used for Reinforcement Learning tasks with discrete action space. Is there any implementation of the algorithm (or other policy gradient algorithm) for continuous action space?

More specifically, is it possible to implement REINFORCE for bipedal locomotion-"humanoid-v2" from OpenAI Gym?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can stable baseline package: https://github.com/hill-a/stable-baselines

Training an agent is as simple as this:

```
import gym
from stable_baselines.common.policies import MlpPolicy
from stable_baselines.common.vec_env import DummyVecEnv
from stable_baselines import PPO2

my_env_id = 'Humanoid-v2'

env = gym.make(my_env_id)
# Vectorized environments allow to easily multiprocess training
# we demonstrate its usefulness in the next examples
env = DummyVecEnv([lambda: env])  # The algorithms require a vectorized environment to run

model = PPO2(MlpPolicy, env, verbose=1)
# Train the agent
model.learn(total_timesteps=10000)

# Enjoy trained agent
obs = env.reset()
for i in range(1000):
    action, _states = model.predict(obs)
    obs, rewards, dones, info = env.step(action)
    env.render()
```